# making position sizing calcualtor, using plot function in if statement

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to make a position sizing calculator that tells me how many shares I can buy or short based on how much dollar I am risking, and how much capital I have.

for example:

max_risk = 50

risk_per_share = high - low (let's say .2)

capital = 3000

price = close (let's say 6)

size_based_risk = max_risk / risk_per_share

size_based_capital = capital / price

In this example,  size_based_risk = 250 shares and size_based_capital = 500 shares

I want to display the lesser of the two so I wrote the following code:

if (size_based_risk < size_based_capital)
plot(size_based_risk)
else
plot(size_based_capital)

I expected the code to display the size_based_rsik (250) since it's less than the size_based_capital (500) but I get:

line 18: Mismatched input 'plot' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Thank you

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

max_risk = 50
risk_per_share = .2
capital = 3000 
price = 6 

size_based_risk = max_risk / risk_per_share
size_based_capital = capital / price



if (size_based_risk < size_based_capital)
   plot(size_based_risk)
else
   plot(size_based_capital)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't use `plot` inside of an `if` statement, you can decide which series you plot according to the a condition you decide.

for example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

max_risk = 50
risk_per_share = .2
capital = 3000 
price = 6 

size_based_risk = max_risk / risk_per_share
size_based_capital = capital / price

size = size_based_risk < size_based_capital ? size_based_risk : size_based_capital

plot(size)
```